# Recursive algorithm to find the smallest element

Tags: algorithm, search, recursion, binary-tree

I want to write a recursive algorithm to find a smallest element.
I draw a binary tree in which leaf represents the elements and internal nodes are smallest elements after comparison.

Input to algo is :

5 3 1 9 8 7 6 10

Binary Tree :

[image]

Output : 1

I need to find an algorithm that somehow incorporates this binary tree.  First compare pair of elements and than reduced the problem to n/2 then n/4 .. and when n become 1 we get the answer.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: And your question is... and you have tried...

Comment: using non-recursive algorithm (for loop) we can easily find a smallest element but i want to find the smallest element using recursive algoirithm

Comment: Can you describe how a recursive algorithm would traverse your tree?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that finds the smallest value in a tree:

```
function smallest(tree)
    if isEmpty(tree)
        return infinity
    return min( tree.value,
                smallest(tree.leftKid),
                smallest(tree.rightKid) )
```

But I don't understand your question. If the input is in the form of an array, you don't need to build a tree. Just walk through the array comparing values pairwise, keeping the minimum at each step, and output the minimum at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Use [divide and conquer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm).

Let `M(i, j)` denote the minimum element of the "subarray" `[i...j]`. Then `M(i, j) = min(M(i, k), M(k + 1, j))`, if `i < j` (I leave it to you to figure out a suitable `k`).

Additionally, you need to take care of the case `i = j`.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
mydata = [5 3 1 9 8 7 6 10];
n = 8;
while n > 1
  for ii = 2 to n Step 2
    mydata[ii/2]=min(mydata[ii-1],mydata[ii]);
  next ii
  n = n/2;
wend
```

Comment: no recursive actually , and algorithm should work similar like binary tree i've shown .

Comment: Just saw your comment above. I guess this is not recursive...

Comment: It does work like your binary tree in that it compares pairs, and works its way up your tree... `mydata` keeps shrinking in size, and represents "all the numbers at the next level up" - but it is not recursive.